# general Complex solution of irreducible quartic polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, roots-of-unity

I encountered a question asking to find the general solution of
$x^4+(x-1)^4=0$, surely it has no real solution.
I tried $x=(±\sqrt{i}(x-1))$ and $±(\sqrt{-i}(x-1))$, but I was able to find some particular solution only in the form $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\cot(θ/8)}{2}$$
where I got $π/8,7π/8,-π/8,3π/8$ but unable to get the general solution.
In the book the solution
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\cot(2k+1)π/8}{2}$$
where $k$ runs from $0$ to $8$.
Can anyone please help me in finding the correct form.
I am getting $3-4k$ instead of $2k+1$ which is wrong. Also why the book writes $0$ to $8$ for $k$ although its quartic.

Comment: I have edited now

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: Thanks@Parcly Taxel excellent trick to solve really cleared where my concept was wrong

Comment: $\cot$ has period $\pi$, so the solutions in the book are not all distinct. Similarly, you write $7\pi/8$ and $-\pi/8$, which also give the same solution. There are four distinct answers among the ones in the book, which have $\cot(n\pi/8)$ for $n=1, 3, 5, 7$. These are the same as the four Parcly Taxel gives, with $n=1,3,-3-1$.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing . The book may have a typo mistake. Thanks for removing my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through this slower: clearly $0$ is not a solution, so we can divide by $x^4$:
$$1+\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)^4=0$$
$$\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)^4=-1$$
$$1-\frac1x=e^{ik\pi/4}$$
where $k\in\{\pm1,\pm3\}$. Finally
$$x=\frac1{1-e^{ik\pi/4}}$$
which, as you have noted, is equal to
$$x=\frac12\left(1+i\cot\frac{k\pi}8\right)$$